# Detect click on "empty" area

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Let's say we have next html/css: http://jsfiddle.net/rbDKm/2/

```
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="actions-row">
            <div class="action ">home</div>
            <div class="action ">search</div>
            <div class="action ">settings</div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions-row">
            <div class="action">...</div>
            <div class="action">...</div>
            <div class="action">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

What I need is to detect any clicks, which were made on an "empty" area.
In provided fiddle, empty area would be everything, which has white or orange color.

Is there any technique/approach for doing this?

Comment: Blacklist the unclickable areas or whitelist the clickable ones.

Comment: *"In provided fiddle, empty area would be everything, which has white or orange color."* What are those areas? People shouldn't have to go to the fiddle to help you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Human brain (or at least mine) has a much worse HTML/CSS parsing/rendering capability than the machine and in some cases, such as this one, an image is indeed worth more than 1000 words.

Comment: explain purpose of needing to target click on empty area

Comment: @Shomz: Then the image should be *in the question*. There's a reason we keep this stuff on-site. But it's much more likely to be useful to *say* what areas the clicks should be ignored for, as in my answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder We can't have rendered markup in the question, you know what I meant. Yeah, I have a feeling if OP knew to *say* which element are to ignore, he'd practically get the answer to his question.

Comment: @Shomz: Yes, I knew what you meant. We **can** have pictures in the question, which is what I meant.

Answer (score 5):

With your markup as you have it now, I *think* that means you need to detect clicks outside of any `div.action`, `#header` or `#footer`.

To do that, you hook `click` on `body`, and then look at the path it took to get to `body`:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var elm = e.target;
    while (elm !== document.body) {
        if (elm.id === "header" || elm.id === "footer") {
            return;
        }
        if (elm.tagName.toUpperCase() === "DIV" && /(?:^| )action(?:$| )/.test(elm.className)) {
            return;
        }
        elm = elm.parentNode;
    }
    // If we got here, it's on one of the desired areas
});
```

There are a couple of variations on that you could do. For instance, instead of `className.match` you could use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) on modern browsers. And modern browsers also offer [`Element#closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) which you could use instead of the loop.

Alternately, you hook `click` on `body` and hook `click` on the relevant other elements and prevent the click from propagating:

```
function stopTheEvent(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // It's one of the desired areas
});
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#header, #footer, div.action");
var index;
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    list[index].addEventListener("click", stopTheEvent);
}
```

...but that seems messier.

---

Note: In the above, I haven't allowed for IE8's lack of `addEventListener`. If you need to support IE8, look at `attachEvent("onclick", ...)` and use `window.event.returnValue = false;` to stop propagation (or use a library that abstracts these things away).

Comment: Chrome 67 complains: `Uncaught TypeError: elm.className.matches is not a function`

Comment: @posfan12 - Thanks for flagging that up!! It's a common typo of mine, should have been `elm.className.match`. But it *really* should have been `regex.test(elm.className)` rather than `match`. Fixed above, with further notes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "target" of the event, and check it's class/id

http://jsfiddle.net/yryQ6/

When you bind the click event, use the event, get the target and ask for it's class:

```
$('#content').on('click',function(e){
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('action')) {
    // click on an action
  } else {
    // click on smething that's not an action, in this case, action-row o actions, your empty area
  }
}
```

EDIT: assuming you use jquery, you should be able to use something similar with javascript events